# How to retrieve the specified parameters in a file (Shell Scripting )?

Tags: bash, unix

Here is my query :

```
/path/newdir/newtext.csv
```

newtext.csv looks like below :

### Record 1

```
line 1
line 2
Sample Number: 123456789 (line no. 3)
|
|
|
|
|
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21)
|
|
|
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)
```

### Record 2

```
line 1
line 2
Sample Number: 363214563 (line no. 3)
|
|
|
|
|
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21)
|
|
|
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)
```

### Record 3

```
line 1
line 2
Sample Number: 987654321 (line no. 3)
|
|
|
|
|
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21)
|
|
|
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)
```

Assume there are such 100 records in a newtext.csv
So, now i need the parameters of the entered i/p string, which is something below

Example Input Search String :

```
123456789
```

Example Output :

```
Sample Number: 123456789
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z
```

This is what exactly i need. Can you please help me ?

Comment: @ Siva Charan : Thank u very much for putting up in a correct manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plain input<sup>*</sup> string,

```
grep -F "InputString" -A27 inputFile.csv | sed -n '1p;19p;$p'
```

For pattern(Extended-regex)<sup>*</sup> string,

```
grep -E "InputPattern" -A27 inputFile.csv | sed -n '1p;19p;$p'
```

#### Script:

```
user$ cat script.sh

#!/bin/bash 
grep -F "$1" -A27 inputFile.csv | sed -n '1p;19p;$p'

user$ chmod +x script.sh
user$ ./script.sh "inputString"
```

#### Edit:

Non-line number based solution,

```
#!/bin/bash 
grep -F "$1" -A27 inputFile.csv |sed -n "/$1/p;/^Time\s[^:]*:/p"
```

***** *The input must be unique to the file.*

Comment: @ Prince John Wesley : Thank U very much, it's absolutely working fine.

Comment: Yeah, it ws mismatch with the line number. Bt ur command is absolutely perfect. Thank U very much. What does the symbol -F denote here ? Is the symbol '|' used to concat the two sommands ?

Comment: remove `-F` if you want to treat your input as regex pattern. `-F` helps to treat the input string as plain text.

Comment: Is the symbol '|' used to concat the two commands grep & sed ?

Comment: Thank U very much Prince John Wesley. It's really helped me alot. Keep ur support. I'm very new to this forum. Any suggestions to improve are most welcome.

Comment: @ Prince John Wesley : Are there any other solutions without counting the line numbers ? It'll be very helpfull if it's in the shell scripting.

Comment: @ Prince : for the same query, hw can v put it in a shell scripting ? Like, it has to ask for the user to enter the search string. After entering the search string, it has to display those 3 parameters. Hw can v do it ?

Comment: Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). script added. Use the other answer for user input.

Comment: Click on FAQ link or see at right-top corner (adjacent to search textbox)

Comment: Non-line number based solution posted. Next time, try something and post what you tried so that others will help u out.

Comment: grep filter matched line and the next 27 lines, sed takes the input and filters the same input string (i.e) first line and those lines that start with '`Time `some text followed by `:`'.

Comment: @ Prince : I don't know how to write scripts. By the way what does the input string mean in user$ ./script.sh "inputString" ?

Comment: @ Prince : Whai if Connect time & disconnect time parameters are present instead of Time In & Time Out. How can we write in Non-line number based solution ?What does $1 mean ?

Comment: Please move extended conversations to [chat].

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

**csv.txt (Input File)**

```
Sample Number: 123456789 (line no. 3)
|
|
|
|
|
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21)
|
|
|
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)
line 1
line 2
Sample Number: 363214563 (line no. 3)
|
|
|
|
|
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21)
|
|
|
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)
line 1
line 2
Sample Number: 987654321 (line no. 3)
|
|
|
|
|
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z (line no. 21)
|
|
|
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z (line no. 30)
```

**csv.sh (Code)**

```
echo "Enter your search string:"
read name
grep -A 10 "$name" csv.txt | grep -v "|" | awk -F "(" '{print $1}'
```

**Output**

```
Enter your search string: 123456789 

Sample Number: 123456789
Time In: 2012-05-29T10:21:06Z
Time Out: 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z
```

Comment: @ Chronicles : That doesn't work according to our requirement. What exacltly cat csv.txt | grep -A 10 "$name" | grep -v "|" | awk -F "(" '{print $1}'does ?

Comment: @James grep -A 10 will get the details "after" 10 lines of match of the required query like "1234567" . Then grep -v will remove all the lines containing '|' . Then , at last the awk command will filter and print the required data.

Comment: Hi Chronicles, Thank u for ur input. What do u mean the lines containging '|' here ?

Comment: @ Chronicles : Is it possible to get the output in the form as below:

IMSI number is : IMSI : 123456789
Connected Time is : Time In :2012-05-29T10:21:06Z
Disconnected Time is : Time Out : 2012-05-29T13:07:46Z

Comment: @JackieJames: `|` is to pipe the output of one command to input of other

Comment: @JackieJames: Ask different question as different post. it will help the visitors.

Comment: @ Prince John Wesley : Thank U. Even I'va also faced the same kind of prob while using this. I'll do it.

Comment: @ Chronicles : The command cat csv.txt | grep -A 10 "$name" | grep -v "|" | awk -F "(" '{print $1}' doesn't get our required output.

Comment: @JackieJames cat csv.txt | grep -A 10 "123456789" | grep -v "|" | awk -F "(" '{print $1}' ..... It will give output if ur input is same as mine...$name is used in the script (generalising)

Comment: I didn't get u. Bt input is different from yours.

Comment: @James oho .. if u give the same input as mine.......like maintaining single log file where all records are appeneded....then the script will work...else it will give erronous result..

Comment: @ Chronicles : Then what else is the solution?

Comment: @James See if u append all records in a single file ... the way i did....den u can run the script...u will get the correct output.....just you need to put all records in a single file.